# Which John Sheppard was Rodney referring to in S5E19?

Tags: stargate-atlantis

In Stargate Atlantis, Season 5, Episode 19 - Vegas, we are presented an alternate reality of the universe.
At one point, we find out that:

> McKay tells Sheppard that a little while ago, he and his team
> accidentally opened a rift in space/time and visited another reality,
> in which that Sheppard is somewhat of a hero having saved the world
> several times over
> [SGA Wiki](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Vegas)

Is Rodney referring to the reality we are familiar with in the show, or do we simply not know?
Also could It possibly have something to do with episode 5, "Daedalus variations"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Sheppard did McKay refer to in S05E19](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64473/which-sheppard-did-mckay-refer-to-in-s05e19)